# Should I use connection pooling?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am writing a ETL project in JAVA. I will connect to the source database, get the data only once, do some transformations and Load the data to a target database.

The point is that I am not connecting to the source or the target database multiple times repeatedly. I just connect once (using JDBC), get the data I need and close the connection.

Should I still use the connection pooling?

Thank you for your views!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Connection pooling is used to get around the fact that many database drivers take a long time to create a connection.  If you only need to use it shortly, and then discard it, the overhead might be substantial (both in time and cpu) if you need many connections.  It is simply faster to reuse than to create a new.

If you do not have that need, there is no reason to set up a connection pool if you don't have it already.  If you happen to have one already, then just use that.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that in some circonstances, using several threads and concurrent connections could improve the overvall throughput of your software allowing for exemple to use all CPU of your RDBMS server, or of the client ETL. This also could help using the fact that several tables could sit physically on differents hardware and thus could be accessed in parallel.

The real impact would really depend of the computers you use and the architecture of the database.

Be carefull that typically ETL have ordering constraints and doing several things at the same time should not violate theses constraints.

Edit : An exemple of this. You can configure Oracle to execute each requests using several cores or not. (Depending of configuration and licence if I understand right). So if one request is allowed to use only one core, using several connections at the same time will allow several requests as the same time and better use the CPU resources of the server.